# Format date with date-fns depending on the devices date format

Tags: reactjs, react-native, date, expo, date-fns

Is it possible to format the date from date-fns based on the users devices date format?
for example my provided code always will show 04/29/2023 on any device, but for some users they would prefer format to show that is set in their device, for example 29/04/2023. How to show the date format depending on the users devices date formats?

```
  <Text>
        {format(date, "P")}
  </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Intl` object from JavaScript to format dates according to the user's device locale. Here's an example of how you can use it in React Native:

```
const App = ({ date }) => {
  const formattedDate =  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined).format(date);

  return <Text>{formattedDate}</Text>;
};
```